# omxplayer accelerates all video playbacks after upgrade to Buster

Tags: video, raspbian-buster, update, omxplayer

RPi lovers. Running Buster on an RPi3, which I just upgraded to from Raspbian Stretch. My omxplayer used to work fine right before the upgrade, and now after the upgrade if I try to play a video file (mp4, mkv, whatever...) it does play it back but both video and sound are accelerated (like if you fast forward).

I have searched the Internet to no avail and don't really know where to start debugging this type of questions (I mean I don't even get an error message). What I do get after stopping playback, having run omxplayer from command line, is the following line (among others) which may be relevant:

```
Video codec omx-h264 width 1920 height 804 profile 100 fps 25.000000
```

I'm sort of stuck and would appreciate if anyone could maybe hint at how to try and solve this - where to look, etc. I'll post the output of anything you guys need me to. I have been using my RPi3 for different purposes for over a year now, and I am no beginner in Linux, but I don't know much about omxplayer per se or how it works.

If the question is not clear or is laking information please tell. First time posting on this subforum because I have not found anything that could help me in it. Cheers and thanks in advance for any help!

EDIT: just removed omxplayer with the --purge option and then installed again (after an update), but it does not solve the problem.

Comment: Did you re-flash your sd card with Buster?

Comment: Thank you for answering! No, I did not. I truly upgraded from Stretch via apt, so it is not a fresh install.

Comment: It is recommended to do a fresh install of Buster.

Comment: I ... do not think that is true? In any case, it is far from advised-against - as I have it, but feel free to point me to some official source info - to upgrade from Stretch. At any rate, it should be feasible to debug this problem, I guess. I hope someone has some other idea than this recommendation (if we had to reinstall from scratch every OS everytime something stops working after an upgrade, we would be pretty busy :-))

Comment: 'We do not recommend upgrading an existing Stretch (or earlier) system to Buster – we can’t know what changes everyone has made to their system, and so have no idea what may break when you move to Buster.' https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/buster-the-new-version-of-raspbian/

Comment: My bad, I stand corrected. Thanks for pointing this out. I must say I still hope there is a way of debugging this as it stands ? I would truly love *not* having to reinstall everything ... any hope you reckon?